# How to include opencv.hpp in android studio?

Tags: android-studio, opencv

Trying to include opencv.hpp header in cpp file but cannot resolve it.
Using opencv 3.1.0 in my project.

also the container is not matching which gives several errors.

> Cannot resolve opencv.hpp

[image]

Comment: Don't post code as image - [edit] your question and append it as text